# Login with Angular error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, http

I'm trying to do an API to login, but I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

**My login.service**

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.urlApi + "authenticate",
      null, //body
      {
        headers: Utils.getHeaderLogin(username, password),
        observe: "response"
      }
    ).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

**utils**

```
private static APP_JSON: 'application/json';

static getHeaderLogin(username: string, password: string) {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': this.APP_JSON,
        'user': username,
        'key': password
    });
    return httpHeaders;
}
```

**My login.component**

```
onSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data)
    this.inscricao = this.service.login(data.username, data.password)
      .subscribe((dados: any) => {
        if (dados && dados.headers) {
          console.log(dados.headers);
          const keys = dados.headers.keys;
        }
      },
        erro => this.erro = console.log(erro),
        () => console.log('complete')
      );
    this.userForm.reset();
  }
```

Using postman all works fine, but my backend don't receive any request, so the problem is in my frontend.
I've tried to search a lot on the internet, but without success.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post Utils.getHeaderLogin method code? Or check if there is anything sort of array.length in this method? Also can you console.log(dados) before if in subscribe and see if it logs something?

Comment: I've putted the Utils.getHeaderLogin on the question. And yes, I showed the dados object before subscrible, and it show me username and password. Thanks. @user2216584

Comment: I did ask to log `dados` in `subscribe` before `if (dados && dados.headers) {`. I just want to know if the error occurs after the response come back from the API or before?

Comment: Can you show me your apiUrl?

Comment: When asking about an error, post the exact and complete stack trace of the error. It tells **where** this error is being thrown.

Comment: @nimeresam My URL: urlApi: "http://localhost:8080/BackEnd/api/"

Comment: @user2216584 don't show me any message.

Comment: Just put http:// before your link; it should work.

Comment: I can't believe that I didn't see, but it was this! @nimeresam Thanks a lot!

Comment: You’re welcome...